# Nominalisation and corresponding verbs (German)

Tags: python, dependencies, nltk

Currently, I'm looking for a ressource which contains for a noun the corresponding verb (in German!). For example: "Verständnis <=> verstanden; Schaffen <=> schaffen; Arbeit <=> arbeiten; ...".
Is there already an existing ressource, or how could I build such a file?

Since I didn't find any such ressource, I tried to write my own code to extract a list of "noun <=> corresponding verb". What I did: I took a text and looked for word in uppercase. Afterwards, I looked for words in lowercase with the additional ending "en" and if they were in the text, I got a new pair "noun <=> verb". But as you see in my example, I'm not able to extract "Verständnis <=> verstanden" and so on...so this is not really a good solution :( .

So my question is: If there doesn't already exist such a ressource; how would you extract these correspondances? I'm sure that I should work with some nltk-modules, for the lemmatization and so on...

In any case: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if such a resource is available anywhere. But what might help you searching is the name of what you're looking for: it's called *derivational* relations. Lemmatisation is a step that might help you (eg. for finding out that "Verständnis" is derived from the verb "verstehen" – not "verstanden", which is the past participle), but it won't give you the desired matches across POS.

Comment: There are morphological analyzers that can perform these kinds of derivations, even (with varying rates of success) for unknown words. They are complex beasts, e.g. using "finite state transducer" technologies, and use a combination of general rules and specific entries for irregular forms. Unless you can find a ready to use one for German, you're probably stuck with dictionary approaches.